# JavaFX Accordion doesn't collapse when in tab pan

Tags: javafx

Ok, so I have an accordion which doesn't close properly when it's a child of a Tab Pane but works as expected outside it. I don't know where the problem stems from.

Also, I just found out that resizing the window causes the layout to display properly.

Is there a way to fix this?

Here is the FXML:

```
<AnchorPane maxWidth="350" minWidth="350.0" prefWidth="350.0">
            <TabPane fx:id="tabPane" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0"
                     AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0">
                <Tab text="Friends">
                    <AnchorPane>
                        <Accordion fx:id="accordion2" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="45" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0"
                                   AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0"
                                   AnchorPane.topAnchor="0" expandedPane="$friendsPane">
                            <panes>
                                <TitledPane fx:id="friendsPane" animated="false" styleClass="myClass" text="Friends">
                                    <ScrollPane fitToWidth="true" hbarPolicy="NEVER" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0"
                                                AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0"
                                                AnchorPane.topAnchor="0">
                                        <VBox fx:id="friends" fillWidth="true" styleClass="vbox">
                                            <children>
                                            </children>
                                        </VBox>
                                    </ScrollPane>
                                </TitledPane>
                                <TitledPane fx:id="groupsPane" animated="true" styleClass="myClass" text="Groups">
                                    <ScrollPane fitToWidth="true" hbarPolicy="NEVER" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0"
                                                AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0"
                                                AnchorPane.topAnchor="0">
                                        <VBox fx:id="groups" fillWidth="true" styleClass="vbox">
                                            <children>
                                            </children>
                                        </VBox>
                                    </ScrollPane>
                                </TitledPane>
                            </panes>
                        </Accordion>
                        <Button fx:id="activateCheck" mnemonicParsing="true" onAction="#activateCheck" text="New Group"
                                AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="10" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="10"/>
                        <Button fx:id="createGroup" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#createGroup" text="Create Group"
                                visible="false" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="10" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="10"/>
                    </AnchorPane>
                </Tab>
                <Tab text="Received Requests">
                    <ScrollPane fitToWidth="true" hbarPolicy="NEVER" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                        <VBox fx:id="requestsRecv" minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0"
                              styleClass="vbox">
                            <children>
                            </children>
                        </VBox>
                    </ScrollPane>
                </Tab>
                <Tab text="Sent Requests">
                    <ScrollPane fitToWidth="true" hbarPolicy="NEVER" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                        <VBox fx:id="requestsSent" minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0"
                              styleClass="vbox">
                            <children>
                            </children>
                        </VBox>
                    </ScrollPane>
                </Tab>
            </TabPane>
        </AnchorPane>
```

[Here is what it looks like:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIyLS.png)

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: Probably because you're forcing the height of the `Accordion` by anchoring it to both the top and bottom. Try using a more flexible layout pane (the obvious choice would be a `BorderPane`, with the `Accordion` in the center and the buttons in the bottom).

Comment: @James_D i have another accordion with top and bottom anchoring that works properly. Also it works after resizing every time which confuses me. The problem occurred suddenly after I did some css work but persisted after I striped the stylesheets from the file.

Comment: Create a [mre] so that others can see the problem.

Comment: I've tracked down the problem. The tab pane has a set max and min width but my controller also had a listener set up for a split pane divider that contained my tab pane. A conflict between those 2 caused my problem. Deleting either seems to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was caused by a conflict between setting tab pane max and min width and having the controller set up a listener forcing the split pane that contained the tab pane divider to a set position.